# Web service fails with org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the [my URL] URL

Tags: web-services, websphere, apache-axis

We have a strange situation. It's a web service (svc1) that calls another web service (svc2) on a different box, both in websphere.  Works in every previous environment.

But recently they built out another staging environment as largely a clone of a working one.  The service is failing with this message everytime svc1 attempts to call svc2.

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the  [svc2's URL] URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:304)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:578)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:419)
    ... 45 more
```

The URL is correct. We can point the not-working apps at a database supporting a working set of apps and it works, but when we point the working apps from that other environment at the not-working environment's DB, it stops working.

This seems to indict the DB, yet the error has nothing to do with the DB.  Svc1's only DB call BEFORE the call to svc2 happens well before the service call and works fine according to logs.  The logs indicate svc2 never gets the request.  So how can database be the problem?

I know this isn't alot to go on, but does anyone even have suggestions on where to look to narrow this down?  I can't believe the DB is the problem based on the code and when it's failing...yet the DB swapping test seems to imply it is.

Answer (score 1):

I might be pointing out the obvious, but the error message is telling you one of two things: either svc1 isn't configured correctly to invoke svc2, or svc2 isn't up and running.

For clarity, if I label the working environment: enviornmentA and the not-working environment: environmentB.

Based on what you said, you were able to use environmentB.svc1 to invoke environmentA.svc2? If that is true, than environmentB.svc1 is configured correctly and working. Which leaves svc2. You said svc2 doesn't receive the request, which means its up at least. Well, like you'd mention this isn't much to go on but I'd make sure you configured svc2 correctly, since it is up. Configuring a Web Service can be complicated, but one of the things that can be configured is making a Web Service available to client invocation. So you might want to check out this link for information on how to configure it:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_publishwsdl.html.

There are a bunch of similar articles on configuring your Web Service that might help you to solve what's missing, so I would verify that the configuration for enviornmentB.svc2 matches enviornmentA.svc2 since you know that one is working.